# Timezone convertion between tickers

Tags: pine-script

I'm attempting to color the background on ticker `ES1!` for those bars that fall within the trading session of ticker `SPX`.
We can use the [time(resolution, session)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_time) function to find out if a bar is in a specified session.

```
t1 = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600")
bgcolor(t1 ? color.yellow : na)
```

This works when it's used on ticker `SPX`.
You can see that all bars have a yellow background, as expected.
Why? Because `SPX` trades between `09:30` and `16:00` in the timezone of the `SPX` ticker, which is `America/New_York`.

[image: SPX]

When we switch the ticker to `ES1!`, the yellow background ALSO starts at `09:30`.
The reason for that is that the `session` parameter in the [time(resolution, session)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_time) function, is evaluated in the timezone of the current ticker.

[image: ES1!]

`SPX` trades in timezone `America/New_York`, which is `UTC-4`.
`ES1!` trades in timezone `America/Chicago`, which is `UTC-5`.

So, when `SPX` starts trading in New York at `09:30`, it's only `08:30` in Chicago.
Therefore, I need the yellow background on the `ES1!` chart to start at `08:30`.
However, it's not possible to get the [time(resolution, session)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_time) function to be evaluated in another timezone.

What I need is a [time()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_time) function that also takes the timezone into account.
Ideally like this:

```
t1 = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600", "America/New_York")
```

This would return a non-`na` value on `ES1!` when the current bar falls within the New York trading session.
I know this is not possible with the current [time(resolution, session)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_time) function.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `security` to calculate the time:

```
t1 = security("SPX", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600"))
bgcolor(t1 ? color.yellow : na)
```

**UPDATE**

As Bjorn Mistiaen noticed in comments, the `gaps` parameter must be set to `barmerge.gaps_on`:

```
t1 = security("SPX", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600"), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
bgcolor(t1 ? color.yellow : na)
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Simple and elegant :)

Comment: On second thought, it seems that using the `security` function doesn't return `na` values when it's outside of the "0930-1600" session, causing the background of all bars to be yellow. When using the `time` function on it's own, this does return `na` values when outside of the session. Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: Nevermind. Found it. Have to set `barmerge.gaps_on`. Like this: `t1 = security("SPX", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600"), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)`

Comment: I've created a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62249159/timezone-convertion-between-tickers-part-3) which leaves me puzzled...