# Timezone convertion between tickers (part 2)

Tags: pine-script

This is a follow-up to my previous question about [Timezone convertion between tickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198423/timezone-convertion-between-tickers).

In that [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198423/timezone-convertion-between-tickers), I asked about coloring the background.
Now I'm plotting lines.

I have `high`/`low`/`close` levels which either fall

- within the `SPX` session (blue lines)
- outside the `SPX` session (red lines)

Both levels are plotted on an `ES1!` chart again, which is in a different timezone than `SPX` (1 hour difference).

This is my current script for the lines

```
//@version=4
study("SPX level on ES1!", shorttitle="SPX>ES1!", overlay=true)

f_data_SPX_daily_preSession() => 
    float   _h = na      // High
    float   _l = na      // Low
    float   _c = na      // Close

    if year==2020 and month==06
        if dayofmonth==01
            _h:=3040,_l:=3000,_c:=3020
        else if dayofmonth==02
            _h:=3060,_l:=3020,_c:=3040
        else if dayofmonth==03
            _h:=3080,_l:=3040,_c:=3060
        else if dayofmonth==04
            _h:=3100,_l:=3060,_c:=3080
        else if dayofmonth==05
            _h:=3120,_l:=3080,_c:=3100

    [_h,_l,_c] // Return the values

f_data_SPX_daily_inSession() =>
    float   _h = na      // High
    float   _l = na      // Low
    float   _c = na      // Close

    if year==2020 and month==06
        if dayofmonth==01
            _h:=3050,_l:=3010,_c:=3030
        else if dayofmonth==02
            _h:=3070,_l:=3030,_c:=3050
        else if dayofmonth==03
            _h:=3090,_l:=3050,_c:=3070
        else if dayofmonth==04
            _h:=3110,_l:=3070,_c:=3090
        else if dayofmonth==05
            _h:=3130,_l:=3090,_c:=3110

    [_h,_l,_c] // Return the values

f_getColor(_t, _color) => na(_t[1]) ? color(na) : _color

// Session times
in_spx_session = security("SPX", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600"), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
pre_spx_session = na(in_spx_session) and time(timeframe.period, "0000-0929")
//pre_spx_session = security("SPX", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period, "0000-0929"), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)

// Pre-Session data
[pre_hi, pre_lo, pre_cl] = f_data_SPX_daily_preSession()
preSession_color = f_getColor(pre_spx_session, color.red)
plot(pre_spx_session ? pre_hi : na, color = preSession_color, title="pre_hi")
plot(pre_spx_session ? pre_lo : na, color = preSession_color, title="pre_lo")
plot(pre_spx_session ? pre_cl : na, color = preSession_color, title="pre_cl")

// In-Session data
[ses_hi, ses_lo, ses_cl] = f_data_SPX_daily_inSession()
inSession_color = f_getColor(in_spx_session, color.blue)
plot(in_spx_session ? ses_hi : na, color = inSession_color, title="ses_hi")
plot(in_spx_session ? ses_lo : na, color = inSession_color, title="ses_lo")
plot(in_spx_session ? ses_cl : na, color = inSession_color, title="ses_cl")

// Background
bgcolor(in_spx_session ? color.yellow : color.blue)
```

Which yields this chart on `ES1!`

[image: ES1!]

As you can see, the red lines start at exactly `00:00` on `ES1!`.
That is because the [time()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_time) part in the following line is evaluated in the timezone of `ES1!`.
So this outcome is expected (but not wanted).

```
pre_spx_session = na(in_spx_session) and time(timeframe.period, "0000-0929")
```

Now for my question, which is 2-fold:

1. What I would like is for the red lines to start at `00:00` in `SPX` time.
   At that time, it's only `23:00` in `ES1!` time.
   I know I could hard code that, but I'd prefer not to.
2. The red lines are currently connected, but I'd like them to be disconnected, like the blue lines.

Does anyone have an idea on how that can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no way to access data outside regular hours once you go through `security()`, so we can forget about going that route.
2. Given that you are stuck with evaluating the condition on the chart's info, there's no way around hard-coding the condition, afaict.
3. If you do that, you'll need to fudge the `f_data_SPX_daily_preSession()` function or calls to it because it will then need to return the same levels on 2 different dates (the date of the `23:00` bars and that of the next ones).

> Nice way to manage your color with `f_getColor()`.

Comment: Still trying to not hard-code it. Therefore, I've created a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62249159/timezone-convertion-between-tickers-part-3) which leaves me puzzled...