# Timezone convertion between tickers (part 3)

Tags: pine-script

As mentioned in the answer to [Timezone convertion between tickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198423/timezone-convertion-between-tickers) by [Dennis T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7587913/denis-t),
we can use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_security) function to get the time in another timezone.

Now I was trying to get times from 2 different timezones.

Ticker `CL1!` trades on `Nymex` in New York, in timezone `UTC-4`.
Ticker `ES1!` trades on `CME` in Chicago, in timezone `UTC-5`.

We can see that from the symbol info

[image: Symbol info]

In order to visualize that time difference, I've created a small script that plots the time in both timezones.

```
//@version=4
study("Nymex-CME times", shorttitle="Time")

time_cl1 = security("CL1!", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) // UTC-4 Nymex
time_es1 = security("ES1!", timeframe.period, time(timeframe.period), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) // UTC-5 CME

plot(time_cl1, "time_cl1", color.blue)
plot(time_es1, "time_es1", color.red)
```

Since both tickers are traded in timezones that are 1 hour apart, I expected to see a 1 hour time difference.

[image: Time diiference ES1! vs CL1!]

To my surprise however, both times are always exactly the same.
I don't understand that.
Shouldn't there be a 1 hour difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` is the time in the exchange's time zone and when viewed through `security()`, will also be dependent on how the bars from each ticker are mapped to each other. Also, those two markets have a one hour delta in their starting/closing time.

Here, we fetch the Unix time but then convert it to hours in the context of the chart's timezone:

```
//@version=4
study("Nymex-CME times", shorttitle="Time")

time_cl1 = security("CL1!", timeframe.period, timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) // UTC-4 Nymex
time_es1 = security("ES1!", timeframe.period, timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) // UTC-5 CME

hour_cl1 = hour(security("CL1!", timeframe.period, timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)) // UTC-4 Nymex
hour_es1 = hour(security("ES1!", timeframe.period, timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute, second), gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)) // UTC-5 CME

plot(time_cl1, "time_cl1", color.blue)
plot(time_es1, "time_es1", color.red)

plot(hour_cl1, "hour_cl1", color.blue)
plot(hour_es1, "hour_es1", color.red)
```

[image]